# How can I use querySelector on to pick an input element by name?

Tags: javascript

I recently received help on this site towards using `querySelector` on a form input such as `select` but as soon as I took `<select>` out it completely changed what had to be done in the function.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm()">
    Password: <input type="text" name="pwd">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    debugger;
    function checkForm() {
        var form = document.forms[0];
        var selectElement = form.querySelector('');
        var selectedValue = selectElement.value;

        alert(selectedValue);
</script>
```

Before, I had `('select')` for the `querySelector`, but now I'm unsure what to put there.
I've tried multiple things as well as `querySelectorAll` but I can't seem to figure it out.

To be clear I'm trying to pull the `name="pwd"`.

How could I do this?

Comment: The `querySelector` method takes a `selector` argument. The `selector` argument is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas. If you ever stuck on valid selectors the MDN has a great page on [**Selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors). Off course you can always get help on SO as well. I just thought you might find the page a handy reference to have in general :)

Answer (score 204):

You can try 'input[name="pwd"]':

```
function checkForm(){
     var form = document.forms[0];
     var selectElement = form.querySelector('input[name="pwd"]');
     var selectedValue = selectElement.value;
}
```

take a look a this http://jsfiddle.net/2ZL4G/1/

Comment: I've tried but nothing seems to return to me and I get no alert

Comment: Hmm, wth.. I've tried this so many times and it still doesn't work with this method, but it works in jsfiddle? am I missing something? Also it shows up in the address bar so I know it's getting the input, just I don't get any alerts

Comment: @AnthonyTobuscus: If your code still has the `debugger;` statement in it than this might cause the rest of the code not to execute as it would halt the execution on that line.

Comment: I tried without it though, and multiple other versions of this code, I'll continue to find an answer and when I do I'll post it here, thanks for the time though :)

Comment: the quotation marks around `pwd` doesn't seem to be necessary

Comment: If you need to keep it ambiguous you can use `document.querySelector('*[name=pwd]')`

Answer (score 47):

I know this is old, but I recently faced the same issue and I managed to pick the element by accessing only the attribute like this: `document.querySelector('[name="your-selector-name-here"]');`

Just in case anyone would ever need this :)

Comment: With Chrome version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit) using querySelector with just the name property only returns the first element, so you can't use array access to access any other radio buttons in the set.  Instead, you either need to assign each radio button a unique id or value (which is the normal way to differentiate radio buttons).  So with document.getElementsByName() being depreciated in HTML5, document.querySelector('[name="radio-button-name"][value="unique-value"]') is the best replacement.

Comment: @HowardBrown but if you want to have the array of elements, wouldn't querySelectorAll work better?

Comment: Just sharing, to get the **value** just add `.value` at the end of this code e.g: `document.querySelector('[name="your-selector-name-here"]').value`

Comment: Better now is [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - that'll return all results instead of just the first result.

Comment: in the case of a radio button input(s) shouldn't this be `querySelectorAll` as there would be more that one input with that name

Answer (score 27):

1- you need to close the block of the function with '}', which is missing.

2- the argument of querySelector may not be an empty string '' or ' '... Use '*' for all.

3- those arguments will return the needed value:

```
querySelector('*')

querySelector('input')

querySelector('input[name="pwd"]')

querySelector('[name="pwd"]')
```

Answer (score 9):

Note: if the name includes `[` or `]` itself, add two backslashes in front of it, like:

```
<input name="array[child]" ...

document.querySelector("[name=array\\[child\\]]");
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("[name='array[child]']")` works too and it is a little more readable !

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is an old thread. However, for people who stepped upon this like me, you may utilize the following code.

select the input using elements collection

```js
form.elements['pwd']
```

or using namedItem method under elements collection

```js
form.elements.namedItem('pwd')
```

Answer (score 2):

So ... you need to change some things in your code

```
<form method="POST" id="form-pass">
Password: <input type="text" name="pwd" id="input-pwd">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
var form = document.querySelector('#form-pass');
var pwd = document.querySelector('#input-pwd');
pwd.focus();
form.onsubmit = checkForm;

function checkForm() {
  alert(pwd.value);
}
</script>
```

Try this way.

Answer (score 1):

These examples seem a bit inefficient. Try this if you want to act upon the value:

```
<input id="cta" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
<button onclick="return joinMailingList()">Join</button>

<script>
    const joinMailingList = () => {
        const email = document.querySelector('#cta').value
        console.log(email)
    }
</script>
```

You will encounter issue if you use `this` keyword with fat arrow (`=>`). If you need to do that, go old school:

```
<script>
    function joinMailingList() {
        const email = document.querySelector('#cta').value
        console.log(email)
    }
</script>
```

If you are working with password inputs, you should use `type="password"` so it will display ****** while the user is typing, and it is also more semantic.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` matched the id in document. You must write id of password in `.html`

Then pass it to `querySelector()` with `#symbol & .value property`.

Example:

`let myVal = document.querySelector('#pwd').value`

Answer (score 1):

`form.elements.name` gives better perfomance than `querySelector` because `querySelector` have to look for in entire document every time. In case with `form.elements.name` computer directly gets inputs from form.

Answer (score 0):

It could be interesting, especially if you have multiple forms, to use :

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector("form[name='form-name' input[name='pwd']")
```

useful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#complex_selectors