# Error with html checkbox value retrieval

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

In my html I have:

```
<div id="case_filter" style="float: bottom">
   <input type="checkbox" name="bC" value="B C" checked> No B C<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="fN" value="f NC" > No F NC<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="rR" value="RR" > No RR<br>
</div>
```

I kept the first checkbox checked by default. I want to access the value of the checkbox in my JS. I am doing this below, but it returns null (when I console.log it).

```
 var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.bC:checked').value;
```

Comment: What's the `.bC` supposed to select?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use querySelector on to pick an input element by name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148659/how-can-i-use-queryselector-on-to-pick-an-input-element-by-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is for class selector. `[]` is for name selector. You could try either:

```
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('[name="bC"]:checked').value;
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" class="bC" value="B C" checked> No B C<br>
```

Comment: `[]` is for selecting any attribute, not just the name.

Answer (score 1):

`bC` is value for the name attribute, so it should be:

```
document.querySelector('[name="bC"]:checked').value
```

Answer (score 0):

The element has the name set to bC, not a class named that.
So either add that class to the html (if that was intended) or use this js:

```
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('[name="bC"]:checked').value
```