# How can javascript create a chain of events in a function, so one function does not start until another is completed?

Tags: javascript

Working on code for personal site and I'm trying to rewrite code that is on the Internet so it's even easier to use for me.

The code is from http://cssdeck.com/labs/7bx7mmcm

How would it be possible to add a marker so that after fileToLoad.click(); is pushed through and completed, then loadFileAsText() goes?  Much thanks in advance!

```
<textarea id="BoxText4Load"></textarea>
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" class="hidden">
<button id="loader">Loader</button>
<input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs" style="display: none;"></input>
<button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save file</button>

var loaderbutton = document.getElementById("loader");
loaderbutton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
fileToLoad.click();
setTimeout(function() {loadFileAsText(); }, 3000);
} , false)
```

Code below directly is from above link:

```
"inputFileNameToSaveAs"

function saveTextAsFile(){
var textToWrite = document.getElementById("BoxText4Load").value;
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
if (window.URL != null)
{
// Chrome allows the link to be clicked
// without actually adding it to the DOM.
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
}
else
{
// Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
// before it can be clicked.
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
downloadLink.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
}

downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent)
{
var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
document.getElementById("BoxText4Load").value = textFromFileLoaded;
};
fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: promises might be what you are looking for... https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261

Comment: When you say you'd like to "add a marker", do you mean to add a comment for the dev looking at the code, or to write a function to handle the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) whenever possible. JavaScript allows us to attach functions that are triggered when certain events occur such as clicking an element or when an element changes.

You could add a *click* event for `#fileToLoad`. This will fire as soon as the element is clicked.

```
document.getElementById("loader").addEventListener('click', function(event){
  loadFileAsText()
}
```

If you want the function to run after the file has been chosen, then you can use a *change* event.

```js
function loadFileAsText() {
  console.log('loadFileAsText running!')
}

var loaderbutton = document.getElementById('loader')
var fileToLoad = document.getElementById('fileToLoad')

loaderbutton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  console.log('loaderbutton clicked!')
  fileToLoad.click()
} , false)

fileToLoad.addEventListener('change', function(event){
  loadFileAsText()
})
```

```html
<textarea id="BoxText4Load"></textarea>
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" class="hidden">
<button id="loader">Loader</button>
<input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs" style="display: none;"></input>
<button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save file</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback function (like HarlemSquirrel's comment).

Assuming there is a fair amount of data posting and retrieval, you could also make [get and post](https://plainjs.com/javascript/ajax/send-ajax-get-and-post-requests-47/%20%22%22) requests and define how the client handles the response. I included a vanillaJS link as it seems you're writing that way. A promise, as @Winter mentioned might be more convenient as it reduces the lines you'd write.
I had heard a recent/abbreviated application of promises is [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) but I haven't used that yet. David Walsh has a concise [comparison](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) of the vanillaJS and fetch way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks HarlemSquirrel for the tip on "change".  It led to [Change- Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)
and to find a way to target my input: [How can I use querySelector on to pick an input element by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148659/how-can-i-use-queryselector-on-to-pick-an-input-element-by-name)

The way I wanted the interface to work is to choose the file and then have it automatically load:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('input[name="filetoloadname"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;
},false);

function changeEventHandler(event) {
loadFileAsText();
}


<body>
<input type="file" id="fileToLoad" name="filetoloadname">
</body>
```