# Vanilla JS: How to target an input element by the input-field's name ("name" in DOM tree)?

Tags: javascript

How to target an input element by the input-field's name ("name" in DOM tree), in vanilla JavaScript (ES6 or later)?

I ought to do it with `document.querySelector('')`. I didn't find a way. I only found the older `getElementsByTagName` which per my understanding deals with the HTML element's name and not with a `name` attribute of (usually) an `input` element itself.

Is it possible in ES6 **without jQuery**?

Comment: _"which of course deals with the HTML element's name and not with a `name` attribute"_, hence there's also [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get element by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306129/javascript-get-element-by-name)

Comment: While you can use `getElementsByName`, `querySelector` seems a bit more appropriate here because you want to select only a single element, rather than generate a collection and proceed to select the first item in the collection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `querySelector` you can use any CSS selector. In your case you need to do an [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```js
const one = document.querySelector("input[name=one]");
const two = document.querySelector("input[name=two]");

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
```

```html
<input name="one"/>
<input name="two"/>
```

Comment: Over SO, you earn privileges with rep. Please use them. This is a very basic query which can be solved with googling. Please choose to close such posts as duplicate instead. It will help more.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do it with `querySelector`:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('input[name="inputname"]').value
);
```

```html
<input name="inputname" value="foo">
```

No ES6 support required.

You can do the same sort of thing when you want to select an element with any other attribute, not just `name`s.

Comment: Please choose to close such posts as duplicate instead.

Comment: @Rajesh The duplicate has no example using `.querySelector()` which is what TO has asked for (kind of...).

Comment: Ok, let me share another link with `querySelector` in answer. But the point was, you should look for dupes instead of answering. This will only make content redundant. A user with your rep should know this.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Another possible duplicate with `.querySelector` in mentioned approached: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148659/how-can-i-use-queryselector-on-to-pick-an-input-element-by-name