# How to select all radio groups from a form with ES6?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, radio-group

I want to select all radio groups from a form using the `name` attribute:

```
<form action="#" id="my-form">

   <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" />

   <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" />

   <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" />

</form>
```

As you can see, i have 3 radio groups: question1, quesiton2, question3

So, from JavaScript (Not jquery), i want to create an array that contains the name of this groups: `["question1", "question2", "question3"]` or at least select the first input of each group

I tried to do this using:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name]");
```

But this returns me all inputs, now i don't know how to make a filter to keep just one input of each group, can you help me please?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+select+inputs+by+name) of [How can I use querySelector on to pick an input element by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148659/how-can-i-use-queryselector-on-to-pick-an-input-element-by-name). Also see [the selectors documentation](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inps = document.querySelectorAll("input[name]")
unique = [];
for(var i=0; i< inps.length; i++){
    if(!i || inps[i-1].getAttribute("name")!=inps[i].getAttribute("name"))
        unique.push(inps[i])
}
console.log(unique)
```

This will give you an array of elements with unique names. The first element with the name will be selected from each name.

**How does it work**

1. Loops through the elements
2. If the current element is either the first one (first condition), or if the name of current element does no match with the last element (second condition), the current element is added to the final list.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the  question in the query selector like this

```js
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="question2"]')

console.log(radios);
```

```html
<form action="#" id="my-form">

   <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" />

   <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" />

   <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple selectors here, eg: the first one selecting the radio box and another one the value or any specific data-attr of your choice to group the radio box as in code snippet

```js
const allRadio = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"][value="1"]');
console.log('count of the selected elems is', allRadio);
```

```html
<form action="#" id="my-form">

   <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question1" value="2" />

   <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question2" value="2" />

   <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1" />
   <input type="radio" name="question3" value="2" />

</form>
```